# Fluid Simulation particles appear and disappear randomly

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I'm using the Mantaflow fluid simulation in Blender 2.8 and randomly some particles appear or disappear. Is there a way to tell Mantaflow that the particle count should always remain the same?

I'm simply talking about the FLIP particles, but I've had the same issue with the other particles.

Comment: Do you mean the particle bake? Particles appearing and disappearing is intentional. For example, if you have a high energy liquid sloshing around then it would have a lot of spray and foam, meaning more particles. When it settles down, it will have less energy and be more calm, resulting in fewer particles needed to simulate realism.  There is simply no way to tell mantaflow to make sure particle counts remain the same without taking the cost of making a simulation extremely unrealistic.

Comment: Yes I was talking about the baked FLIP particles. Ok I see... that's unfortunate, but so be it!